# Dynamics CRM : Not able to locate Fields on Entity Forms

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am working on CRM 2013 on premise. I want to add 'Is Kit' field on Product Entity Form.

As I am new to CRM, I am not able to find a way so that in the Selection I can have this field to drag and drop it on the form.

Please see below screen, where we have this field available Out of the Box.

[image]

Now, I want to insert this field on the Entity form. But it is not available to drag and drop from the Field Explorer. Please see below image.

[image]
How do I add this field on the form? or Do I need to create Custom field for 'Is Kit'?

Please suggest me.

Thank you,
Mittal.

Comment: hey i think it will be already on the form without label in header or footer region. Could you check there any fields.

Answer (score 2):

First, double check the display name is "Is Kit".  Your screenshot is showing the schema name but the field listing shows display names.

If you don't see your field, then uncheck the checkbox called "Only show unused fields".  This is just above your field listing on the form editor screen.

If unchecking allows you to find your field, then that means the field was already added to the form.  With 2011/2013 it is ok to have the same field multiple times, but that's why it isn't showing up in your available field listing.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form property as follows. It will show the image

Go to form->Form property->Under display->click the check box (Show image in the form)->Save->publish all customization's.

Comment: How's this setting related to the question ?